# How to do the group-by operation in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a `tensor` of data point `points` whose shape is `(1, #data, #dimension)` and another one is `dist`, whose shape is `(#cluster, 1, #dimension)`, and the last one is `cluster`, has shape of `(#data, )`, which indicates the index of cluster the `points` belongs to. And now I want to calculate the mean value in each cluster. So the expected output should has shape `(#cluster, 1, #dimension)`. I did something like `tf.gather(points, cluster)` and got a output has shape of `(#data, #data, #dimension)`. Now I have no idea how should I deal with it. Could you please help me?

EDIT:

For instance, the `points` is `[[2, 3], [1, 4], [8, 10]]`, and the `cluster` is `[1, 0, 2]`, the expected output should be `[[[0,0], [2, 3], [0, 0]], [[1, 4], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [8, 10]]]` so it is convenient to calculate the mean.

Comment: Try using `tf.unsorted_segment_sum` to sum the points that share the same cluster value.